# Is getdate() enough to figure database order of operations?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, getdate

Suppose we have tables A,B,C,D, and each of them has a column [date1] which we positively know is filled during `insert` with the `getdate()` function.

Is it safe to assume that if row R1 on some table has an earlier value than row R2, on the same or another table, then the insertion of R1 happened indeed before R2, leading to ability to debug code in triggers, procedures etc?

It seems obvious, but one can never be sure enough. In contrast, the definition for rowversion seems more concrete about this.

For the sake of this question, I am not including `update`s, but feel free to expand.

Comment: In short, no, for many reasons: `GETDATE()` uses `DATETIME`, which has precision limited to 3 1/3 milliseconds, it's dependent on the system clock, which in bad cases may be limited to 15.6 milliseconds of precision, and perhaps most importantly, the value of `GETDATE()` is fixed at evaluation time and so is neither unique per row affected nor an accurate indication of when a row was actually written. If you need a ballpark indication of when things happened a human-readable time is good enough, but if you need it absolutely accurate to the individual row it's not.

Comment: Another complication is that for each time in the database, you would have to make sure what the source is: if clients can supply an explicit value for them this could obviously be different from the server's clock (or from different clients). A common source of this is when a column uses `GETDATE()` for a default, but clients are still allowed (or expected) to supply times themselves.

Comment: Last but not least, of course: `GETDATE()` uses wall-clock time as supplied by the system, and this clock is not guaranteed to be monotonously increasing. Even `SYSUTCDATETIME()` (which is better, as it solves the problems of internal accuracy and time zone adjustments) is still subject to someone changing time manually (though you can at least arrange for the server to be well-behaved through NTP and leaving the damn clock alone).

Comment: Also consider the system clock changes due to drift and it being fixed by NTP, your records would then look out of order.

Comment: @DavidG: typically NTP tries very hard to only adjust the clock forward (and changing the tick rate to slow it down or speed it up as necessary), avoiding hard backwards adjustments as much as possible to prevent exactly that sort of problem from happening. If your drift gets bad enough it may become unavoidable, but that typically needs manual intervention anyway.

Comment: Have a look at Example C in [Sequence Numbers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/sequence-numbers/sequence-numbers?view=sql-server-ver16#typical-use). It seems to be more appropriate for what you are trying to accomplish. And think `BigInt`.

Comment: Also consider that a system that does not use UTC (or a local timezone that does not observe DST), `getdate()` shifts by an hour twice a year so, as Jeroen mentioned, `sysutcdatetime()` solves _two_ problems.

Comment: I have to say that needing to figure out what rows are inserted into various tables before others in order to debug triggers sounds like there are a lot of design issues in this database.

Comment: @Sean Large The combination of multiple parallel invocations along with cross-server non-support of distributed transactions is what led to this question

Comment: A note - internally the call to getdate() (or whichever date fn you use) is not tied to the transaction committing in some order.  You can have "big expensive query with getdate()" that starts running, calls getdate, spends time executing, and commits after a much faster query doing similar things.  So, please do not expect perfect alignment of when a query looks at a clock vs. when it is committed.  Temporal tables do have a form of this problem and they up the isolation level, effectively, to try to provide a form of this ordering you seek.  I'm not saying make everything temporal but fyi